# Matlab and color point specific areas

Tags: matlab

I have a grid with fixed points and random generated user's positions.

Distances for each point and user are measured from the beginning of the axis 0.0. I want to associate each user to the closest fixed point. I calculate both distance vectors and the min of them per user is pointing to the closest fixed point.

But i am stuck on finding a working way so each fixed point and associated user have something same in plot, p.e. same color and color area.

So my problem is two dimensional:

1. First is to manage to associate each user to its closest fixed poind
2. How to color the result.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the nearest point simply compute the euclidean distance between each `user` point and the complete set of `fixed` points. Then the index of the shortest distance will also be the index of the `fixed` point.

```
dist = calc_dist(fixedPts, aSingleUserPt)
[~, idx] = min(dist);
```

To solve the color problem, you'll need to create a colormap from a `fixed` point index to a unique color. Then when you `plot` a user point you will set the color of the plot equal to the colormap evaluated at `idx`

*Note* the euclidean distance is very easy to calcuate:

```
euc_dist = sqrt( (x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 );
```

There are [functions on File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/71-distance-m) that will let you compute this quickly.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestions. The euclidean way was easy and already known, but the association of users per closest fixed point was my problem, sorry if my question was not clear.

Answer (score 1):

For the point searching I would use [`dsearchn`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/dsearchn.html) for this kind of thing. You can use it with or without delaunay triangulation depending on the ratio of users to fixed sites. I tend to use it the quick and easy way, which in your case would be:

```
indices_of_closest_fixed_points = dsearchn(fixed_points, user_points)
```

As for the colors I would suggest you define a color map using something like

```
mymap = lines(n)
```

where `n` is the number of fixed points you have. You can then use `scatter` to plot the points with specific colors and sizes. Perhaps something like this to get you started:

```
x = user_points(1,:); 
y = user_points(2,:);
S = []; % point sizes, left empty for now
C = mymap(indices_of_closest_fixed_points,:); %colors

scatter(x,y,S,C);
```

Comment: Hello This scatter looks to work but is very very slow. Also it scatters circles and wanna try to scatter hexagons, but for now i wanna fix the speed problem. I wish i d knew the dsearchn function prior the euclidean way i used. To associate the users to the closest fixed point is done. I appreciate your suggestions, be well.

Comment: I have never had a speed issue with scatter. What size is your data set?

Comment: The problem was the matlab installation. After win7 restore cause win boot HDD was dead, i use matlab installation files on second HDD without reinstalling matlab. After two or three iterations results where weird and slow. I delete matlab and reinstall it and now works fine.